# AppWidget network timeout in the night

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, widget

I am writing an Android widget that should update some information once a new day is detected.
The provider is simple and works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="80dip"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
    android:minResizeWidth="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="14400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/Widget3"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/previewImage" 
    android:configure="com...MYAPP...AppConfigure" 
/>
```

It updates the widget every 4 hours.
If a new day is detected I want to download the new data. This fails in the night (Oreo, API27):

```
private async Task<bool> DownloadNewShifts(Context context)  {
    var request = WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.MYWEBPAGE.com/v3/api/1.0/");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Headers.Add("Com-MYAPP-Request", "Viewer");
    request.Timeout = 1000 * 10;

    var postData = "id=" + lines[0] + "&code=" + lines[1] + "&month=105";
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); 
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    try  {
        using (var stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())  {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)  {
        return false;
    }
….
    return true;
}
```

It works and I get the new data every 4 hours. But during the night I got always the "timeout exception". The strange thing is that the timeout occurs 9-10 minutes after the method was called. So even setting a timeout of 10 seconds, doesn't help.

Is it possible that the "do not disturb" will block my network call? From 8:00 it works and I get the new data.

I don't know how Android processes the widget_update method and why it is not killed after some seconds (if I log and write every action in an event log, I can see how they are written over 10 minutes).

## Edit - network problem

Ok, for the internet connection. It seems to be one of the buggandroid. It has to do with the battery optimisation, present since Android 7:

https://forums.androidcentral.com/showthread.php?t=811927&p=5991696&viewfull=1#post5991696

Once I disabled it for my app, the request doesn't time out anymore. Here a description, how disable battery optimisation for a single app on Android:

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/androids-battery-optimization-harm-good/

But this is not really a solution. I think I have to live with this bug and update the widget once I have a connection to the server.

Still doesn't know why the timeout is up to 30 minutes (this night)!
I casted the Webrequest so I was able to set also the readwrite timeout:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.MYWEBPAGE.com/v3/api/1.0/");
request.Timeout = 1000 * 10;
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000 * 10;
```

It has no effect. Seems to be more a Xamarin bug. I probably will use WebClient: I don't have many options and features but the timeout occurs after 15 seconds and not after 20-30 minutes! Or I should check if the widget has access to the internet before calling this function.

Comment: The most easy way to set up a repeating update is declaring the android:updatePeriodMillis in the appwidget-provider xml.  However, Android's AppWidget update framework ignore any of its value less than 30 minutes - it is not providing update more than once in every half an hours.

We can use AlarmManager's setRepeating function to raise an Intent repeating for a set interval.  In this case, we set the updatePeriodMillis="0". For more detail you can access http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/repeating-update-on-appwidget.html

Comment: Hi Lucas, this is because I set android:updatePeriodMillis="14400000" (4 hours). It should be long enough. I noticed that setting the timeout to 5000 the timeout exception rise after 5 minutes and setting the timeout to 10000 the exception rise after 10 minutes on the `GetRequestStreamAsync` call. Still doesn't know why and don't know how to solve it.